# Is there any other way to add dynamic data into a jQuery Mobile Page than appending through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I started with jQuery Mobile recently. I am using it along with Cordova. To start with, I am building a simple hybrid app with SQLite database. I have read through the documentations of JQM. From what I see in most of the examples is that the data into the Page is entirely fed through JavaScript like illustrated below:

I have a page like this:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="home-rh">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="" data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>My Holiday Calendar</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="myContent">Hello 2</div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home-all">All Holidays</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">RH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CH</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I am aware data can be dynamically added through JavaScript like this:

```
$("#myContent").append('****MY HTML goes here*****');
```

**My Question:**

1. Is there a better way to dynamically add content to my page in JQM without having to write my HTML in JavaScript code and append it like above?

Any other good practices also welcome.

**I have read through many forums..but could not clear my head on this.**

**EDIT:**

Had asked 3 questions initially but cut out the other two to be more specific. 
@Gajotres gives inputs on all the three questions..
Here are the other 2..

2. Is it good that we are adding HTML through JavaScript in JQM? Wouldn't it be a problem if my HTML is huge?
3. I am pretty much sure a lot of good apps have been built on JQuery Mobile.. I want to know some patterns they generally use in such cases.

Thanks

Comment: three different questions in one, too much, don't you think? :)

Comment: @Omar : Yes, but all these questions overlap..so thought it wise to not ask them as separate questions :)

Comment: Some users might consider your question an off-topic - too broad and/or opinion-based.

Comment: @Omar : Agree. Edited my question to have only one question :)

Comment: Man now my points look out of place ;)

Comment: @Gajotres... now it isn't out of place..;) Edited to include the other questions.

Comment: My advice, if you like jQuery give Kendo UI a chance. After some time you can move to Kendo UI + AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all good questions, but you are using a wrong framework here. Don't get me wrong, like Omar, I'm helping other people with jQuery Mobile questions, but your question is beyond jQuery Mobile.

1. There's a better way, but jQuery Mobile will not work properly with it. You will need to use some MVC framework, currently the best one is AngularJS (this is my subjective feeling; you can also use BackboneJS, KnockoutJS or EmberJS). AngularJS directives will make this step almost painless, it will do everything automatically, you will not need to do anything at all.

   As long as you have some data source (model) AngularJS will automatically append page data. This is an excellent approach, but you will need to turn jQuery Mobile page routing (it is incompatible with  AngularJS routing). This way you will loose jQuery Mobile transitions.

   Even better AngularJS uses it own template engine (made to mimic MustacheJS or HandlebarJS).
2. This is the least important problem here. jQuery Mobile already has a big DOM imprint it doesn't matter which way you fill it with additional content. Appending additional content will take only a fraction of a second (50ms usually, I did some benchmarks 2 years ago), but page enhancement process will require much more time. So this is the biggest problem here.

   Basically, it doesn't matter how you append your data, bigger problem is how much is appended.
3. Read **[this](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)** article if you want to learn secrets of a good jQuery Mobile page architecture.

My advice, skip jQuery Mobile and go with Kendo UI, or Ionic Framework, or Onsen UI. Kendo UI is very similar to jQuery Mobile, but it has own MVC framework. It even uses jQuery. Or you can use it with AngularJS (they recently made this version also).

Ionic and Onsen UI are completely AngularJS driven mobile frameworks. They are very fast, but you will need to spend some time learning AngularJS.

Comment: Agree @Gajotres.. I have previously used Ionic and OpenUI5.. both are great :).. Just wanted to give JQM a try.. Thanks for your insights.. and yes I frequently visit your blog..Its great!

Answer (score 2):

You could use some sort of templating framework like Handlebars.js or Jade. Here is a tutorial on Handlebars with jQuery Mobile

http://www.gajotres.net/using-jquery-mobile-with-handlebars/

Comment: Hey @Gajotres, isn't that post I linked to your post?

Comment: Yes, your answer is linked to my blog :) Omar and I have blogs dedicated to jQuery Mobile. This is Omars blog: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks @unobf ..:) The article points me to something I was on look out for :)